# Scroll a CAShapeLayer into view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, cashapelayer

I have a `UIView` inside a `UIScrollView` and am using a `CAShapeLayer` with several sublayers to draw in the view. In some cases the layer is not visible and I'd like to scroll the view so that the layer becomes visible. To scroll I'm using:

```
[self.scrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(0, offset) animated: NO];
```

I'm having a hard time to figure out what the offset is. I've tried to get the enclosing rect, but that always has the origin at (0,0).

How can I calculate the position of the layer to use in offset?

**UPDATE:**

This seems to work to get the enclosing rect for all sublayers:

```
- (CGRect) enclosingLayerRect
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectZero;

    if (self.sublayers.count)
    {
        CAShapeLayer *layer = self.sublayers[0]; // need to get the first one, otherwise the origin will be (0,0)

        rect =  CGPathGetBoundingBox(layer.path);

        for (CAShapeLayer *layer in self.sublayers)
        {
            CGRect layerRect = CGPathGetBoundingBox(layer.path);
            rect = CGRectUnion(rect, layerRect);
        }
    }

    return rect;
}
```

Feel free to comment if there is a better, easier way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `convertRect:toView:` method to convert the frame to the scroll view's coordinate system, and the resulting rect should give you the required content offset.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. But the question remains, how do I get the enclosing rect of the layer relative to the view?

Comment: See my update above, `convertRect:toView:` is not necessary with that approach.